# JwtSecurityToken understanding and exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm fairly new to `JwtSecurityTokens`, and I try to understand the different aspects of it and furhtermore the whole `claimsidentity` and `claimprincipal`, but that's another story.

I try to generate a token in **C#** by using the following code:

```
private const string SECRET_KEY = "abcdef";
private static readonly SymmetricSecurityKey SIGNING_KEY = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SECRET_KEY));

    public static string GenerateToken(string someName)
    {
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims: new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, someName), 
            },
            notBefore: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime,
            expires: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60)).DateTime,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(SIGNING_KEY, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

> I followed a tutorial on Youtube, but I'm not sure I understand the
>   different parts in the JwtSecurityToken. In addition, when I execute
>   the code through a controller just to try to return a token, it
>   returns an error, saying: "IDX10603: Decryption failed. Keys tried:
>   '[PII is hidden]'".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

The algorithm HS256 requires the `SecurityKey.KeySize` to be greater than 128 bits and your key has just 48. Extend it by adding at least 10 more symbols.
As for "PII is hidden" part, it was done as a part of GDPR compliance effort to hide any stack or variable info in logs. You should enable additional details with:

```
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

Answer (score 12):

You should add enough **characters** to your **secret key**, when you set your secret key here,

```
//your SECRET_KEY = "abcdef"
new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SECRET_KEY));
```

change it to

```
new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("somethingyouwantwhichissecurewillworkk"));
```

this should work.